# separate json object into different index

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have following array which consist of json objects:

```
items = [
         {
           id: '1',
           name: 'Josh',
           transactionDate: '2012-08-10',
           creditAmount: '200',
           numberBank: '12345',
         },
         {
           id: '1',
           name: 'Josh',
           transactionDate: '2012-08-14',
           creditAmount: '159',
           numberBank: '12345',
         },
         {
           id: '1',
           name: 'Josh',
           transactionDate: '2012-08-15',
           creditAmount: '3421',
           numberBank: '12345',
         },
         {
           id: '2',
           name: 'George',
           transactionDate: '2012-09-15',
           creditAmount: '6000',
           numberBank: '13345',
         },
         {
           id: '2',
           name: 'George',
           transactionDate: '2012-09-16',
           creditAmount: '6565',
           numberBank: '13345',
         }
        ]
```

I want to separate the array index for each same `id`

as an example :

```
        [
         {
           id: '1',
           name: 'Josh',
           transactionDate: '2012-08-10',
           creditAmount: '200',
           numberBank: '12345',
         },
         {
           id: '1',
           name: 'Josh',
           transactionDate: '2012-08-14',
           creditAmount: '159',
           numberBank: '12345',
         },
         {
           id: '1',
           name: 'Josh',
           transactionDate: '2012-08-15',
           creditAmount: '3421',
           numberBank: '12345',
         }
        ],
        [
         {
           id: '2',
           name: 'George',
           transactionDate: '2012-09-15',
           creditAmount: '6000',
           numberBank: '13345',
         },
         {
           id: '2',
           name: 'George',
           transactionDate: '2012-09-16',
           creditAmount: '6565',
           numberBank: '13345',
         }
        ]
```

How to do like that ? thanks

Comment: `I have following array which consist of json objects:` - no, you have a javascript array full of javascript objects - nothing about this has anything to do with JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `reduce` to group by `id` and then the values of the resultant using `Object.values`
**EDIT**
`??=` is the [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). The right hand side will be assigned whenever the left hand side is `null` or `undefined`.

```js
let items = [         {           id: '1',           name: 'Josh',           transactionDate: '2012-08-10',           creditAmount: '200',           numberBank: '12345',         },         {           id: '1',           name: 'Josh',           transactionDate: '2012-08-14',           creditAmount: '159',           numberBank: '12345',         },         {           id: '1',           name: 'Josh',           transactionDate: '2012-08-15',           creditAmount: '3421',           numberBank: '12345',         },         {           id: '2',           name: 'George',           transactionDate: '2012-09-15',           creditAmount: '6000',           numberBank: '13345',         },         {           id: '2',           name: 'George',           transactionDate: '2012-09-16',           creditAmount: '6565',           numberBank: '13345',         }        ]
        
const res = Object.values(items.reduce((acc,curr)=> {
  acc[curr.id]??=[]  //similar to acc[curr.id] = acc[curr.id] || [] in this case
  acc[curr.id].push(curr)
  return acc
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Code indentation should be improved, use of `const` instead of `let` and instead of using `if` statement a more clean solution would be Logical nullish assignment: `acc[curr.id] ??= []`

Comment: hi @YosvelQuinteroArguelles thanks for pointing them out. the snippets here are weird I cant get them to properly indent ever. didnt really care about let and const here tbh. i will improve the answer