# How to isolate duplicates by property from an array of objects

Tags: javascript

From this array of objects, I'd like to get multiple arrays containing the objects that have the same values for the "id" property:

```
var obj1 = { id: 1, name: "apple"};
var obj2 = { id: 2, name: "pear"};
var obj3 = { id: 3, name: "melon"};
var obj4 = { id: 4, name: "cherry"};
var obj5 = { id: 2, name: "banana"};
var obj6 = { id: 1, name: "pinapple"};
var obj7 = { id: 1, name: "peach"};
var array = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, obj6, obj7];
```

Example of the arrays I'd like to retrieve:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "apple"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "pinapple"
}, {
  id: 1,
  name: "peach"
}]

[{
  id: 2,
  name: "pear"
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: "banana"
}]
```

Comment: something similar i had https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455033/separate-json-object-into-different-index/71455073#71455073

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `groupBy` utility function in a library like `lodash` that you can use, otherwise you'd have to write your own version of that. It would look something like

```js
function myGroupById (array) {
    const group = {};

    array.forEach(elem => {
        group[elem.id] = group[elem.id] || [];
        group[elem.id].push(elem)
    })

    return group;
}

function extractDuplicatesOnly(array) {
    for (const obj in array) {
        if (array[obj].length < 2) {
            delete array[obj]; 
        }
    }
    return array;
}
myArray = myGroupById(myArray);
myArray = extractDuplicatesOnly(myArray);
console.log(myArray);
```

applying that to your data will yield an object that looks like this:

```js
{
  1: [
    { id: 1, name: "apple" },
    { id: 1, name: "pinapple" },
    { id: 1, name: "peach" },
  ],
  2: [
    { id: 2, name: "pear" },
    { id: 2, name: "banana" },
  ]
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much Joshua. I made some edits to your answer to match my question.